# Cant find variable error while executing the javascript to change the webelement

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am getting "cant error variable : e " while i am executing the following command to change the webelement text value

```
sel=webdriver.PhantomJS()
sel.get=('http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest')
elements=sel.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@href="/questions/31762200/traversing-through-nsset-is-slower-than-traversing-nsarray"]')
e=elements[0]
sel.execute_script(" e.text='testing' ")


WebDriverException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Can't find variable: e","request":
{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"95","Content-Type":"application/
json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:38324","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"sessionId\": \"255a60c0-384f-11e5-
b643-5d2e25d3f62d\", \"args\": [], \"script\": \"e.text='testing'\"}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/
execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/
session/255a60c0-384f-11e5-b643-5d2e25d3f62d/execute"}}
```

Screenshot: available via screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python code and the javascript code does not share the varaibles.

---

Pass the variable `e` from the Python side to the javascript by passing additional argument(s) to [`Webdriver.execute_script`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script). In javascript code, you can access the arguments using `arguments` array:

```
sel.execute_script("arguments[0].text = 'testing'", e)
```